# How do you do science on Theories of Everything?

Tags: experimental-physics, theory-of-everything

A theory of everything will always have an explanation for why the observed world fits into it's explanation.
So cries of "it's not falsifiable!" don't really add anything to the discourse. Of course it has a just so story-- it's a theory of everything!

So how do we do science on theories of everything?

Comment: There is no reason that a supposed TOE can’t be falsifiable. Imagine that there were no gravity and the Standard Model were our current TOE. We could of course discover that it made an incorrect prediction about how known particles interact, or that there were new particles or interactions that it didn’t include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong about this, and about what a theory of everything (TOE) actually is.

First of all, as it is currently used in the physics community, "TOE" means a single mathematical framework that merges general relativity and quantum mechanics. How do you "do science" with TOE's? Here are the three initial steps in the process:

1) For a mathematical model to be considered for candidacy as a GR+QM "theory of everything", it has to correctly and accurately account for all particle and gravitational phenomena that current theories (Einstein's general relativity for gravity, the Standard Model for QM) do. These requirements place extremely tight limitations on the structure that any TOE can possibly take. If it does not contain GR and QM as currently known and understood, it is a theory of nothing.

2) In addition, it must make brand new predictions that can be tested by physics experiments. If it doesn't, it might still be an impressive achievement in its own right- which might make it a theory of not very much.

3) If it makes testable predictions but they are wrong, it is a theory of nothing.

Comment: Regarding (2), a new theory that reduces to GR and QFT under appropriate conditions and yet makes no new predictions need not be a "theory of nothing".  It would be impressive to just produce a single theory that does reduce to GR or QFT.  We also might not be able, due to physical limitations of our own measurement abilities, be able to test it in the region where it blends GR and QFT and those theories alone do not work well enough.  That does not make it a theory of nothing, it just makes it unproven.

Answer (score 1):

A 'theory of everything' is not what you think it is. It's not trying to somehow handwavy-highschooly explain everything, but unifiying all known forces of nature, to predict how the universe should look according to that theory.

A 'theory of everything' is still a scientific construct that starts with axioms, held to be true, and derives further statements from those axioms. Derived statements are/will be tested against experimental evidence, and if colliding with it, the theory must be rejected.
Just like any other theory. So I don't see how we won't do science with it.

Of course no functioning theory of everything exists yet.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got "handwavy-highschooly" from my question. I know this is the internet, but I'd appreciate some respect. In the interest of not wasting everyone's time, I thought it would be a good idea to not demonstrate my knowledge of TOE's or what they actually are. I still think my question is interesting and deserves a well thought out answer.

Comment: @JayDouglass: A bit confused on this. How is my answer not answering your question and not thought out? The answer is: We do science with a TOE just like with any other theory. Maybe you should clarify your question about what "doing science with" means and think how to precisely put into words what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

> So how do we do science on theories of everything?

You mean that research into physics will stop if we have a theory of everything?

Think a bit. As far as solid state physics goes, there exists a theory of everything: electromagnetic and quantum theory. Solid state research  has been a vibrant branch of research and continues to be, even though the theory necessary is well known. The complexity of the possible solid states has not been explored and will probably continue to be explored.

So even if a TOE is proposed during our lifetime, the research into various branches of physics will continue because of the complexity of the physical world.

At the moment there are theorists looking for the TOE in string theories, where quantized gravity can be modeled and the standard model of physics can be embedded. But there are thousands of possible theories, and they have not landed the one specific to our world/universe. If or when they do, it will be good to have a possible TOE, but the different branches of  physics will continue pursuing the research in the complexity of the subject and in addition will try testing the TOE at its prediction limits.

After all mainstream thinkers before Galileo thought they had the theory of everything, but observations and experiments proved them wrong. This could be true for a modern TOE, but it will require good experimental accuracies to falsify it and keep on looking for a TOE, which might be what history of science will show in 500 years.

Answer (score 0):

> A theory of everything will always have an explanation for why the observed world fits into it's explanation. So cries of "it's not falsifiable!" don't really add anything to the discourse.

I suspect that this might be what you're thinking:

1. A theory-of-everything would correctly explain everything, and therefore always be true.
2. If it's always true, it can't be found false.
3. If it can't be found false, it's unfalsifiable.

Is that about right?

If so, then this is just confusion over the definition of the word "*falsifiable*".

A theory is *falsifiable* if we can construct an experiment that has an outcome that the theory would purport to predict.  This is, a theory is falsifiable if it could, *in principle*, be found false if it's wrong.

So, say that we have a theory-of-everything that purports its ability to make any prediction, and we always find that it's correct; then, that theory-of-everything would still be both falsifiable *and* correct.

---

#### Related: ["*The exception that proves the rule*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_that_proves_the_rule).

As [Wikipedia notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_that_proves_the_rule), this saying is widely interpreted in different ways.  I suppose some folks might interpret it as:

> Valid rules should have exceptions; rules that're never wrong can't be valid.

I can understand how someone might see this common expression, then hear the word "*unfalsifiable*", and come to the (incorrect) conclusion that theories must make some incorrect prediction to be valid.

- **MYTH:** Theories must be able to produce wrong results to be falsifiable; theories that don't ever produce wrong results are unfalsifiable and thus non-scientific.
- **TRUE:**  Theories must be *hypothetically* able to produce wrong results to be falsifiable; theories that don't ever produce testable results are unfalsifiable and thus non-scientific.